Reference Request for Comparison Theorem of Motivic Cohomology
I encountered the following theorem:

Let $X$ be a smooth scheme over a field $k$, then whenever $p \ge 2q-1$, we have an isomorphism
$$
H^{p,q}(X,\mathbb Z)\cong H^{p-q}(X, K_q^M)
$$
where $K_q^M$ is the $q$th Milnor K-theory.

At first, I thought this followed from the comparison theorem established in Voevodsky's lecture notes on Motivic Cohomology, Theorem 19.1, where we have $H^{n,i}(X,\mathbb Z)\cong \operatorname{CH}^i(X,2i-n)$ for smooth separated schemes $X$ over perfect field $k$, but I can't quite make it out. I am wondering if anyone can provide pointers for a source/reference to this result, or details of the proof, thanks!
